# How to choose the best recommender system? What evaluation metrics to use?

Tags: neural-networks, dataset, model-evaluation, recommender-system

I want to build a recommender system to suggest similar songs to continue a playlist (similar to what Spotify does by recommending similar songs at the end of a playlist).

I want to build two models: one based on **collaborative filtering** (so I need something like user ratings about songs?) and another one, a **content-based model** (so I need song's features like tempo, bpm..) to compare their results and choose the best one *which returns the best songs that a user will like and certainly will add to his playlist .*

---

Now, I have two questions:

1. Where can I find a dataset with useful data for this type of work?
2. How can I measure the results to choose the best model? **How can I understand that *a specific song* recommended by my model is better than another one to continue my playlist?** (e.g. in classification tasks I can use confusion matrix to have a clear view of the corrected and wrong classifications, but with recommender systems how can I evaluate the *"correctness"* of the prevision?

---

**EDIT:** for example, my CF model suggest me a song, while CB model suggest me another different song as first result to ontinue my playlist. I surely like the first song and add it to my playlist, while the first song suggested by the second model is awful and I surely wouldn't add to the playlist.
**How can I objectively evaluate the prediction's goodness and so the goodness of the models?**

Comment: What do you need this algorithm for? Usually to judge "best" you need to consider your objectives and constraints. The "useful" data will depend on what kind of problem are you solving.

Comment: Are you asking "what metrics can be used for evaluating recommender system"?

Comment: Yes, what metrics can I use to evaluate the "precision" of the suggestions of a recommender system? 
How can I say if a suggested song, in this case, is the best song to suggest? If another model suggest me another song that I like more, how can I evaluate the results from the two models in order to say which model predicts better songs for me?

Comment: Why isn't NDCG "appropriate"? Start with that metric and if you think the results are not fit for your purpose, expand as to why they aren't.